# My friend in Yemen cannot open this site

Tags: support

I have a friend in Yemen who is learning Japanese. Yesterday, I suggested her this site, but she couldn't enter here since then. She says she gets this error message (she translated it to English):

> Sorry! Google Chrome is unable to contact

What can be the problem? Is Stack Exchange blocked in some countries? Is this temporary? Can you please give us more information on this issue?

Comment: I think you should ask this on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), they can help you more there.

Answer (score 4):

Does your friend have this issue with any other sites? Is this an issue in all browsers?

The error message you provided is pretty terse, but it suggests that the domain doesn't get resolved at all - which means unfortunately there's nothing we can really do about it. It's likely that the problem is somewhere between your friend and our servers.

If she has a `traceroute` log handy, maybe we can get something out of that, but it's unlikely that it's something under our control.

Comment: Yemen is on a internet content filtering watch list, the inclusion of the religious sites in the domain might have caused it to be blocked.

Answer (score 4):

Yemen is one of the countries that is on the watch list for internet content filtering and it is entirely possible that the *.stackexchange.com domain might have gotten blocked for one reason or another. Check with her to see if she can get to one of the other sites within the network or if she can get to the main http://stackoverflow.com site. If there is still an issue it might be worth elevating up to [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) to see if they might be willing to get another exchange domain that doesn't get picked up by the filtering software.

Answer (score 0):

Have her try to use a proxy server.  Or set one up for her.